# How to redirect stdout & stderr for current process?

Tags: c++

My application loads various shared libraries that utilize `printf()` and the like to print diagnostics. However, I need to redirect these diagnostics to Android logcats. The general idea here is being able to register some sort of callback to logs sent to `printf()` so I can redirect them wherever I want (this makes the question platform-agnostic, I hope).

Most of the answers I've found on SO involve doing this to *child* processes, however that is not the case for me here. Furthermore, the solutions I've seen involve `fork()` and such which cause my process to be effectively cloned multiple times and my application is not designed for this.

What options do I have here? I only want to redirect logs printed within my application's own running session, i.e. within the same address space. I don't need to support piping of child processes and such. I'm not sure if this simplifies things.

Note that I'm OK with this solution being specific to Linux.

Comment: The example given at ["man dup2"](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html) might prove useful.

Comment: Check out [`freopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) if you want to redirect to a file. But to run arbitrary code, the easiest solution is a separate process and a pipe.

Comment: Would it be more feasible to design a very small process dedicated to doing nothing but redirecting & piping? That way I'm not cloning my main process for this purpose?

Comment: I don't understand the "cloning my main process" bit. Your process is as big as you make it.

Comment: What I mean is, the solutions I've tried invoke `fork()` and when I look at my `ps` listing, I see multiple copies of my process.

Comment: I'm not sure that's as much as a problem as you're making it out to be. Your application doesn't need to be "designed for this" - forking it doesn't run it again from scratch. The code post-fork knows that it's forked and does specific things before exiting. This already happens more often than you realise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Use [std::freopen](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/freopen):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::printf("This will be printed to console.\n");
  if(std::freopen("log.txt", "w", stdout)) {
      std::printf("This will be redirected to log.txt\n");
      std::cout << "This will also be redirected.\n";
      std::fclose(stdout);
  }
}
```

### [See it live!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0eca7168a2c8a35)

---

The same can be done for `stderr`. A harder problem is actually being able to use the "old" stdout again, after it was reopened. `std::freopen` closes the old file descriptor, so we have to duplicate it and keep it separate from our evil redirection. Here is a POSIX way (not standard C++) to do it:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  auto actual_stdout = fdopen(dup(fileno(stdout)), "w");
  std::printf("This will be printed to console.\n");
  if(std::freopen("log.txt", "w", stdout)) {
      std::printf("This will be redirected to log.txt.\n");
      std::cout << "This will also be redirected.\n";
      std::fclose(stdout);
  }

  // Note: using fprintf. C++ streams will still not work.
  std::fprintf(actual_stdout, "This will be printed into the console, too.\n");
}
```

### [See it Live!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f95fbb93107d5f7)